# Hacer compatible app android para Tablets

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

He creado una App en android studio la cual probé siempre mediante un emulador de teléfono. Al momento de intentar abrir la App dentro de una tablet esta se cierra automaticamente. Tengo entendido que la aplicacion puede funcionar dentro de distintos dispositivos sin mayores problemas, mi idea es mostrar el mismo diseño en la tablet.

este es el error que me genera:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.appmuestreo, PID: 2576
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.appmuestreo/com.example.appmuestreo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.example.appmuestreo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070061
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1233)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.loadDrawableFromDelegates(ResourceManagerInternal.java:252)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:139)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
    at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:107)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
    at com.example.appmuestreo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Agradeceria informacion extra para resolver el problema :C .
Gracias.

Comment: Agrega el layout que carga tu MainActivity, es ahí donde se encuentra el problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error sucede al cargar el layout de la Activity `MainActivity`, y el problema se produce al tratar de "inflar" un `ImageView` :

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11:
>   Error inflating class ImageView

Ya que **el `ImageView` que se carga en el layout de tu `MainActivity`, esta haciendo referencia a un recurso que no existe en tu proyecto**:

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
>   ID #0x7f070061

por esta razón se produce el cierre de tu aplicación.

---

Comentas que:

> probé siempre en teléfono pero al momento de intentar abrir la App dentro
>   de una tablet esta se cierra automáticamente

Pueden ser dos causas:

- La imagen o recurso que hace referencia el `ImageView` se encuentra en un directorio por ejemplo `/drawable-v24` pero no en `/drawable`.
- La imagen que hace referencia el `ImageView` en realidad no es una imagen, puede ser por ejemplo que en `/drawable-v24` se tiene una imagen pero en `/drawable` la imagen es corrupta o no es una imagen en realidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente era la imagen dentro del proyecto tenia el nombre de "Imagen.jpg-v24" solamente hizo falta cambiar el nombre . 

Tambien me asegure e instale un plugin llamado android drawable importer el cual entrega distintos tamaños de la misma imagen para evitar este problema.

Comment: Excelente @MatiasNavarro saludos!